# Do FOF missiles respect the safety setting?

Tags: eve-online

As far as I understand, FOF missiles used to be rather dangerous to use in high-sec as they could attack neutral targets and cause CONCORD to destroy the ship using them.

A lot has changed in that area with the complete overhaul of Crimewatch. So I'm wondering how FOF missiles are affected by the safety setting?

If I set my safety to green, can FOF missiles still attack targets that would cause a CONCORD reaction? And how would the behaviour of FOF missiles change if I set my safety to orange or red?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FOF missiles have been rather safe to use for years now. Back in Revelation II, they were changed from attacking the closest object/target/ship/anything in space to only attacking mission rats and large collidable objects in high-sec, and any ships and large collidable objects in low- and null-sec.

What's dangerous about them is that [they have a penance to choose large collidable objects instead of players or rats](https://forums.eveonline.com/default.aspx?g=posts&t=189494), making them a massive wastage factor along with their diminutive ability to reduce the mission rats' combined DPS on your ship.

A general rule of thumb regarding FoF-missiles: recycle them.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/Eve/comments/1cg5wf/fof_missiles_and_safety/) FOF missiles are supposed to only attack valid targets (that won't get you CONCORDed) however there are a sufficient number of bugs and caveats to this that you should still expect to get your ship blown up if you use them.

Comment: I used them in a Serpentis Blockade without problems. I don't think your answer is doing the mechanics justice.